# How can I get an exact match for search-members?

Tags: mailchimp-api-v3.0

I am noticing that emails with '+' in them are not being searched as an exact match in search-members. For example {'query': 'email:bob+subscription_to_list_one@example.com'} will return bob+subscription_to_other_list@example.com in the full_search element and 0 entries in the 'exact_matches' element.

Does anyone know how exact-matches are found?
Does anyone know how to tell mailchimp to not treat the '+' character as special?

Answer (score 1):

Encoding the plus sign '+', will fix the issue

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that removing "email:" from the query populates the exact_matches element and returns nothing extra. Strange, but true.